# Remove duplicates in array of objects with various properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects with some properties.
If cod and art already exist in the array, I want to remove the repeated ones.

I created a function for this, but my result is wrong... instead of having 3 lines, I have 2.

Can anyone help me?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-atiqy7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**.TS**

```
 data = [
    {
      cod: 1.13,
      art: 'BCC'
    },
    {
      cod: 1.13,
      art: 'BCC'
    },
    {
      cod: 1.13,
      art: 'BCC'
    },
    {
      cod: 1.14,
      art: 'BCC'
    },
    {
      cod: 1.14,
      art: 'BCC'
    },
    {
      cod: 1.13,
      art: 'AAA'
    },
    {
      cod: 1.13,
      art: 'AAA'
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    var filtered = this.data.filter(function(el) {
      if (!this[el.cod && el.art]) {
        this[el.cod && el.art] = true;
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }, Object.create(null));
    console.log(filtered);
  }

  //Expected Output

  // data = [
  //   {
  //     cod: 1.13,
  //     art: 'BCC'
  //   },

  //   {
  //     cod: 1.14,
  //     art: 'BCC'
  //   },
  //   {
  //     cod: 1.13,
  //     art: 'AAA'
  //   }
  // ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    var filtered = this.data.filter(function(el) {
      if (!this[el.cod + el.art]) {
        this[el.cod + el.art] = true;
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }, Object.create(null));
    console.log(filtered);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use map to achieve your goal

```
ngOnInit() {
    let map = new Map();

    this.data.forEach(eachItem => map.set(eachItem.cod + '-' + eachItem.art, eachItem));

    console.log('unique items:', Array.from(map.values()));
}
```

Comment: Thats a smooth idea with the map!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set to remember the pushed objects and only add if they are unique.

Here's the edited [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rmvpdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
data = [{
    cod: 1.13,
    art: 'BCC'
  },
  {
    cod: 1.13,
    art: 'BCC'
  },
  {
    cod: 1.13,
    art: 'BCC'
  },
  {
    cod: 1.14,
    art: 'BCC'
  },
  {
    cod: 1.14,
    art: 'BCC'
  },
  {
    cod: 1.13,
    art: 'AAA'
  },
  {
    cod: 1.13,
    art: 'AAA'
  }
];

const unique = data.reduce(((set) => (acc, curr) => {
  const { cod, art } = curr;
  const key = `${cod}_${art}`;
  if (!set.has(key)) {
    set.add(key);
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
})(new Set()), []);

console.log(unique)
```